# how to access session from next to previous page

Tags: php, ajax, session

I am in trouble.in my login page i am using ajax.a pop come in my page for login an after authentication using ajax it returns to the same calling page.i am using session for tracking my login.but when i reload the page the session expires which i dont want.i need only session should expires when we close browser.How is it possible to?

part of code i used(from top to bottom)

**request code**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
 ?>
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["manager"]))
{
echo'<script>document.getElementById("accordion").style.display="block";</script>'; 
}
?>
```

**response code**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','1');
 ?>
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["uname"])&&isset($_GET["upass"])){   
$manager=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_GET["uname"]);
$password=preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9]#i','',$_GET["upass"]);
include"connect_to_mysql.php";
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM login WHERE  username='$manager' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1");

$existCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($existCount==1){
/*while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$id=$row["id"];
}*/
//$_SESSION["id"]=$id; 
$_SESSION["manager"]=$manager;
$_SESSION["password"]=$password;
echo("success");

}
else
{
echo("fail");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: If something does not work, please review your code. Check with the manual you're doing everything right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `session_start()` at the beginning of both files.

Comment: Wow, it works at it was announced? Cool!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `session_start()` at the beginning of both files. 
If you add `session_start()` in your connection file, please remove it.

Add it separately in the request code file and the response code file.